# Django custom view "You don't have permission error"

Tags: django, django-admin

I have created my own view for Django admin. Here, I want to add a link to order to view order without disturbing change_form like this.
[image]

I added following code to admin.py.

```
 def get_urls(self):
    urls = super(OrderAdmin, self).get_urls()
    custom_urls = [
        path('order/<int:order_id>/view', self.view_order, name="view_order")
    ]
    print(urls)
    return urls + custom_urls

def view_order(self, request, order_id):
    order = Order.objects.get(pk=order_id)
    return render(request, 'shop/order.html', {'order':order})
```

Now when I click the link following screen appears.

[image]

What's the problem ? How can I get the original dashboard retaining what I have done ?

Answer (score 0):

you can have custom decorator with needed permission.

For example if you view should be available one for logged in users:

```
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated

@permission_classes((IsAuthenticated, ))
def view_order(self, request, order_id):
    order = Order.objects.get(pk=order_id)
    return render(request, 'shop/order.html', {'order':order})
```

if your is available for anyone you can use `AllowAny`:

```
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny

@permission_classes((AllowAny, ))
def view_order(self, request, order_id):
    order = Order.objects.get(pk=order_id)
    return render(request, 'shop/order.html', {'order':order})
```

Also, you can write your view as a class and reload `def has_change_permission(self, request, obj=None):` method

Comment: rest_framework ?? I don't want to use that ?

Comment: I wanted a way to get previous context and pass it to render method.